# Query unread messages

Tags: mongodb

I'm stuck with some MongoDB query. I have a simple structure to manage threads and messages in my application.

```
{
  participants: [
    'u1,'u2'
  ]
  messages: [
   {text: 'some message', readBy: ['u1','u2']}
   {text: 'some other message', readBy: ['u1']}
  ]
}
```

Being *'u2'* I would like to get this specific thread returned by the query. This is how far I have come, but as soon as one message was read by *'u2'*, it is not returned anymore as one of the messages has been read by *'u2'*.

```
Threads.find(
        {
            $and: [
                {'participants': this.userId},
                {'messages.readBy': {$nin: [this.userId]}}        
            ]
        }            
    )
```

How can I achieve this without changing my datastructure?

Comment: What is the expected result of your query?

Comment: In the end I need it to count all unread threads, i.e. any thread having at least 1 unread message should be selected. I will use this information to display a badge on the webpage so the user knows there is some unread messages. Coming from SQL I'm unused to store stuff denormalized so I ended up with the given structure. It is important to note that I'm using Meteor, so not everything MongoDB supports works out of the box & is reactive.

Comment: If the answer you accepted worked, then there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to perform an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation that will transform your `messages` array in Json object which will help you to request exactly the item you need.

The following query will give you the records where "u2" is participating with only messages not read by "u2" :

```
db.threads.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$messages"
}, {
    $match: {
        "participants": "u2",
        "messages.readBy": {
            $nin: ["u2"]
        }
    }
}]);
```

this will give you :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("579d0fc8733ac30906524be4"),
    "participants": ["u1", "u2"],
    "messages": {
        "text": "some other message",
        "readBy": ["u1"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admit I have never used aggregations before. Thank you very much for the competent answer. I asked for not changing my data structure, but negating readBy (i.e. using unreadBy) would make it possible to use a regular query as far as I understood it? Would you recommend to use an aggregation or is it generally better to change the data structure so I can use a regular query?

Comment: that's up to you. If you use a `find` request, you will have to parse the result according to your likings whereas using aggregations, mongoDB engine do it for you. aggregation will take a little longer to execute  but you can group, create field, project etc... Consider that with an aggregation you can have one single array with all the new message unread whereas with a `find` you will have to iterate through the result and build this array yourself